# Add event listener inside class constructor or outside of component class?

Tags: javascript, react-native

There is a component `SplashScreen` in my React Native (0.61.5) app. A event listener is needed in the `SplashScreen`. Tried the following 2 ways to add the event listener:

```
import nodejs from 'nodejs-mobile-react-native';

console.log("Nodejs obj : ", nodejs);
nodejs.start("main.js");
nodejs.channel.addListener(
"message",
(msg) => {
    alert("From node: " + msg);
    console.log("Message from nodejs : ", msg);
},
this
);

class SplashScreen extends React.Component {
..........
}
```

Another one is to add the event listener in the class constructor:

```
import nodejs from 'nodejs-mobile-react-native';

class SplashScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._isMounted = false;

        this.state = {
            idx:1,
        };

        console.log("Nodejs obj : ", nodejs);
        nodejs.start("main.js");
        nodejs.channel.addListener(
        "message",
        (msg) => {
            alert("From node: " + msg);
            console.log("Message from nodejs : ", msg);
        },
        this
        ); 

      };
.....
}
```

Both codes are working fine. IIs there any difference between the two from code point of view, such as pattern and performance?

Comment: Try avoid doing any work in constructors. Put the event handler installation in the life cycle methods or your own, to be called *after* the object has been instantiated.

Comment: In life cycle methods make sense. What is the benefit not in constructor? I thought constructor is for initial setup of the class. The listener still can be removed before unmount.

Comment: The constructors purpose is to initialise the instance, e.g. setup `this.state`. It should however not register the instance elsewhere, e.g. by adding event listeners to something. That should be a separate action, a separate method call.